# french Installation of civicrm 5.27.2 on drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

i want to install civicrm in french in my drupal 8.9.2 website. after following the instruction in this website https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/wikis/Administrator-Guide. it's not work for me. please show me the best method install
cheers

Comment: what did you try? Did you get any error when enabling french language?

Comment: after activating the multi language option on the administration interface and adding the language I would like to the l10n folder in the civicrm module root, it does not display in the language choice

Answer (score 2):

If you've already installed civi and you're able to get to the administer - localization - languages page, then the following is probably the simplest at this point:

In civicrm.settings.php (in web/sites/default), add this line to point to the l10n folder:

`define('CIVICRM_L10N_BASEDIR', '/full/path/to/l10n');`

OR

Move your l10n folder into vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core.

The first is slightly better because you can put l10n somewhere that won't get deleted when you upgrade, so then I'd also move l10n somewhere completely outside civi.

Comment: after doing it's no work for me